# Missing version.pm installing Crypt::SSLeay on RHEL7

Tags: linux, perl, dependencies, redhat

I am trying to install Crypt::SSLeay that is required to launch PulledPork from Snort. I am working on a fresh Red Hat Linux Enterprise 7 Server (in VM) with Perl 5.16-3.
I am installing every Perl module from search.cpan.org and I need to get source code to compile myself.

At first, I wanted to install Crypt::SSLeay with

```
perl Makefile.PL
make
sudo make install
```

Then I got a bunch of dependencies to install first.

- ExtUtils::CBuilder
- ExtUtils::MakerMaker
- Perl::OSType
- IPC::Cmd
- Params::Check
- Locale::Maketext::Simple
- Module::Load::Conditional
- Module::Load
- Test::More
- ExtUtils::MM_Unix::tool_xsubpp

But now I am stuck with this.

```
Can't locate version.pm in @INC (@INC contains: /usr/local/lib64/perl5
/usr/local/share/perl5 /usr/lib64/perl5/vendor_perl
/usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl /usr/lib64/perl5 /usr/share/perl5 .) at
/usr/local/share/perl5/Module/Load/Conditional.pm line 12. BEGIN
failed--compilation aborted at
/usr/local/share/perl5/Module/Load/Conditional.pm line 12. Compilation
failed in require at /usr/local/share/perl5/IPC/Cmd.pm line 60. BEGIN
failed--compilation aborted at /usr/local/share/perl5/IPC/Cmd.pm line
60. Compilation failed in require at /usr/local/share/perl5/ExtUtils/CBuilder/Base.pm line 10. BEGIN
failed--compilation aborted at
/usr/local/share/perl5/ExtUtils/CBuilder/Base.pm line 10. Compilation
failed in require at
/usr/local/share/perl5/ExtUtils/CBuilder/Platform/Unix.pm line 5.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at
/usr/local/share/perl5/ExtUtils/CBuilder/Platform/Unix.pm line 5.
Compilation failed in require at (eval 1) line 2. BEGIN
failed--compilation aborted at (eval 1) line 2. Compilation failed in
require at Makefile.PL line 5. BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at
Makefile.PL line 5.
```

I install version (http://search.cpan.org/~jpeacock/version-0.9917/lib/version.pod) but it told me :

```
ERROR from evaluation of
/home/pdavid/Downloads/version-0.9917/vutil/Makefile.PL:
ExtUtils::MM_Unix::tool_xsubpp : Can't find xsubpp at
/usr/local/share/perl5/ExtUtils/MM_Unix.pm line 3753.
```

Comment: First, there is no reason for anything to [have a dependency on `Crypt::SSLeay`](https://metacpan.org/pod/release/NANIS/Crypt-SSLeay-0.73_06/SSLeay.pm#DO-YOU-NEED-Crypt::SSLeay?). Second, I think you have borked your Perl install: `corelist version

Data for 2017-03-20
version was first released with perl v5.9.0`

Comment: I filed a [bug report with `pulledpork`](https://github.com/shirkdog/pulledpork/issues/258). I don't see any reason it needs to depend on `Crypt::SSLeay`.

Answer (score 1):

Red Hat Enterprise Linux (and Fedora) ship a subset of Perl in the `perl` package; this is why you're missing `version.pm` although the software assumes it's there; that's why Sinan mentions it is in `corelist`.

The solution is to first install the `perl-core` package on your system, then your system will have all packages from core installed, and then you can install your software:

```
sudo yum install perl-core
```

By the way, you can also install Crypt::SSLeay via `yum`:

```
sudo yum install "perl(Crypt::SSLeay)"
```